# How to check for a empty element within a list of elements in python

Tags: python

Say for example i have a list of lists that contain data like this:

```
    customer1 = ['Dan','24','red']
    customer2 = ['Bob',' ','Blue']
    customerlist = [customer1, customer2]
```

I would like to run a line of code that will run a function if one of these elements is empty. For example something like this:

```
    for c in customerlist:
        if not in c:
            ***RUN CODE***
        else:
            print('Customer Complete')
```

That way if a customer is missing data i can run some code.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is an _empty element_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
    if not in c:
```

You want this:

```
    for val in c:
        if not val.strip():
```

Which basically checks if any of the strings is empty (empty strings are "falsey" in Python).  Stripping first detects strings which only contain whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` to check for  `' '`

```
for c in customerlist:
    if ' ' in c:
        RUN CODE
    else:
        print('Customer Complete')
```

Comment: This considers `'Bob '` to be an empty string.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile: I don't think so, you're looking at the wrong layer of the onion.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile no, it doesn't. `c` is a list, not string.

Comment: To expand on the above, you may also do: `if any(x in a for x in (' ', '', 'empty', None)):` to check for multiple representations of an empty index.

Comment: @Guy Right, I was looking at the wrong list, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers given by Guy and John are correct, but perhaps it would interest you to look into [objects](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp):

```py
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name, age = None, color = None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age if age else age_function_generator()
        self.color = color if color else color_function_generator()
```

To create a customer, then, simply do:

```
c1 = Customer(name = "Dan", age = 24, color = "red")
c2 = Customer(name = "Bob", color = "Blue")
```

In the case of `c2` the function `age_function_generator()` (not defined here) would be called. To access the attributes of the customer object one would do:

```py
print(c1.name, c1.age, c1.color)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Python Regular Expression to search for blank entries on the list. A Regular Expression is a sequence of characters that define a pattern. For more information on Python Regular Expression, kindly visit:
[w3school link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and [Google Developer link](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions)

Kindly replace the following code

```
for c in customerlist:
        if not in c:
```

with the following code:

```
for i in range(len(customerlist)):
    for j in range(len(customer1)):
        emptylist = re.findall('\s*', customerlist[i][j])
```

Dont forget to include 'import re' at the beginning of code to import Python re module

The complete code:

```
import re
customer1 = ['Dan','24','red']
customer2 = ['Bob',' ','Blue', ' ']
customerlist = [customer1, customer2]

for i in range(len(customerlist)):
    for j in range(len(customer1)):
        emptylist = re.findall('\s*', customerlist[i][j])
if(len(emptylist) == 0):
    print('There are no blank entries')
else:
    print('There are blank entries')
    #code goes here to do something
```

The output:

```
There are blank entries
```

In the code:

```
emptylist = re.findall('\s*', customerlist[i][j])
```

re.findall() search for zero or more instances(*) of white space character(\s) with customerlist being the iterating list. customerlist[i][j] as it is a list of lists.